# About the consecutive dimensions of k-eigenspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, generalized-eigenvector

If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of matrix $A$, is it possible that for some positive integer $n$, dim($N(A-\lambda I)^{n+1})$-dim($N(A-\lambda I)^{n})>1$. 
I am studying generalised eigenspaces and in all the examples I have read so far, dimension is increasing by 1 as power of $A-\lambda I$ is increasing until it hits the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda$.

Comment: I guess you have two different $n$'s in your question.

Comment: Yes.. let me edit

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) is highly related to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $\lambda=0$, $n=1$ and $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}$